# C# AES-GCM split into parts

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I'm using AuthenticatedAesCng to encrypt some large data. Once another party receives parts of the data, it should start decrypting it. This is not possible with normal GCM, because it generates the authentication tag at the end, which is required for the entire decryption. So, I asked how I would do that [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72512/decrypt-authenticated-cipher-while-still-encrypting/72519?noredirect=1#comment160444_72519). I should split the encryption into multiple parts pass a authentication tag for after every part.

The issue here is the way how I should implement this. Generating a new IV for every part seems like a bad idea. I should increase the counter value, but C#s AuthenticatedAesCng doesn't  have that. **What should I do?**

Comment: Looks like you know how you would do dat, but .net API does it a different way. I would consider checking if there is some crypto library out there that makes the things the way you need or dig into https://referencesource.microsoft.com and AES / CGN classes.

Comment: @bradbury9 It's really hard to find a good, well maintained crypto library. I only found BouncyCastle, but it hasn't got hardware acceleration :C

Comment: This is a problem I've asked about before here. Somewhere. User @kelalaka had proposed a method that chains together "block" using the tag and the block number as AAD for the next "block". But the first question to be answered on your part is: what will I do with previous blocks of plaintext if the current block fails the tag check"?

Comment: Generating a new IV (nonce) may sound like a bad idea, but using the same one is worse. If you have fewer than 256 segments: random 11 bytes plus the twelfth byte is a counter starting at zero.